# Can not assert the value from Dafny method

Tags: testing, dafny

This is the code for Bulls and Cows game, simply it just we have 2 array a[] and b[] with the same length, if a[i] == b[i] then Bulls += 1, if a[i] in b && a[i] != b[i] then Cows += 1.

I have written the Bulls and Cows function, but the method BullCows have some problem when calculate it, it make my assert fail.

`

```
function bullspec(s:seq<nat>, u:seq<nat>): nat
  requires |s| > 0
  requires |u| > 0
  requires |s| == |u|
{
  var index:=0;
  if |s| == 1 then (
    if s[0]==u[0] 
    then 1 else 0
  ) else (
    if s[index] != u[index] 
    then bullspec(s[index+1..],u[index+1..]) 
    else 1+bullspec(s[index+1..],u[index+1..])
    )
}

function cowspec(s:seq<nat>, u:seq<nat>): nat
  requires |s| > 0
  requires |u| > 0
  requires |s| <= |u|
{
  var extra:= |u|-|s|;
  var index:=0;
  if |s| == 1 then (
    if s[0] in u 
    then 1 else 0
  ) else(
    if s[index] in u && s[index]!=u[extra]
    then (1+ cowspec(s[index+1..],u)) 
    else cowspec(s[index+1..],u)
  )
}

method BullsCows (s:seq<nat>, u:seq<nat>) returns (b:nat, c:nat)
  requires |s|>0 && |u|>0 &&|s|==|u|
  // No duplicates in array
  requires forall i, j | 0 <= i < |s| && 0 <= j < |s| && i != j :: s[i] != s[j]
  requires forall i, j | 0 <= i < |u| && 0 <= j < |u| && i != j :: u[i] != u[j]

  ensures forall k :: 0 <= k < |s| && s[k] !in u ==> b == c == 0
  ensures forall k :: 0 <= k < |s| && s[k] in u ==> (c + b) > 0
{
  var index := 0;
  b := 0;
  c := 0;
  while(index<|s|)
    invariant index <= |s|
    invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < index && s[k] in u ==> (b + c) > 0
    {
      if s[index] in u {
        if s[index] == u[index]{
          b:=b+1;
        } else {
          c:=c+1;
        }
      }
      index:=index + 1;
    }
}


method NotMain()
{
  var sys:seq<nat> := [4,2,9,3,1];
  var usr:seq<nat> := [1,2,3,4,5];

  assert bullspec(sys, usr) == 1; //True
  assert cowspec(sys, usr) == 3; //True

  var b:nat, c:nat := BullsCows(sys, usr);
  assert b == 1; //Not true
  assert c == 3; //Not true
}
```

`
The method NotMain said that assert b == 1; and assert c==3; are not true, this is Dafny language, please could someone help me with this logical, I'm banging my head.

I try put on many ensures in the BullsCows method but there's nothing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the postcondition on `BullsCows()` is not strong enough to prove the final two assertions.  In particular, there is no connection between the operation of `BullsCows()` and the specifications `bullspec()` and `cowspec()`.  You need to connect these things together.

To illustrate I'm going to use a simpler example which is easier to follow.  As for your example above, the final assertion fails in the following:

```
function sumspec(xs: seq<nat>, i: nat) : nat
requires i <= |xs| {
    if |xs| == 0 || i == 0 then 0
    else sumspec(xs,i-1) + xs[i-1]
}

method sum(s:seq<nat>) returns (r:nat) {
    r := 0;
    for i := 0 to |s| {
        r := r + s[i];
    }
    return r;
}

method main() {
    assert sumspec([1,2,3],3) == 6;
    var r := sum([1,2,3]);
    assert r == 6;
}
```

Whilst `sumspec()` is a valid specification for `sum()` we have not connected these two things.  As such, Dafny assumes that `sum()` can return any value for `r`!

To connect the specification (`sumspec`) with its implementation (`sum`) we need a stronger postcondition:

```
method sum(s:seq<nat>) returns (r:nat) 
ensures r == sumspec(s,|s|) {
    r := 0;
    for i := 0 to |s|
    invariant r == sumspec(s,i) {
        r := r + s[i];
    }
    return r;
}
```

Here, `r == sumspec(s,|s|)` connects the specification with the result of our implementation.  We also added a loop `invariant` to help Dafny show this postcondition holds.

Comment: So in method BullCows I'll add ensures b == bullspec(s,u), then the loop I'll add invariant b == bullspect(s,u) too right ?

Comment: Well, that would be a start.  But, I suspect you won't get that loop invariant to verify.  You'll probably need to rework the `bullspec` and `cowspec` I'd imagine.

Comment: Oh thanks, I'll code it again, thanks for your suggestion